# Mindstorms NXT Bluetooth Slow Connecting

Tags: mindstorms, bluetooth

I have just bought a NXT 2.0 and have installed the software on my laptop, and after some trouble getting it to connect I now have it connected any working using bluetooth. However it takes an age to connect, and I wondered if anybody knew why and how to sort it out.

I am running Win7 32-bit, and to get the software running I first had to set it to run as administrator and using XP SP2 compatibility settings, and had to change the bluetooth driver to use the generic MS stack rather than the installed for from the manufacturer. I found these tips on various sites around the web.

Once I had done this I managed to get it working, but now on opening the software and scanning for devices, it takes somewhere in the region of 4-5 minutes to find the device (while it is sat next to the laptop), and then another 2-3 minutes to connect, and then even more annoyingly another 2 minutes when I click close on the devices window. Once this has completed, it works fine and uploads and downloads with no problems, but it just seems really slow getting there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have got that problem too. And this is a bug in the NXT 2.0 system, So there are two solutions:

1- Using the USB Cable instead of Bluetooth as it give no errors and it is faster also it keeps your battery life for longer time.

2-Update your NXT Firmware frequently as the LEGO may be fixed the problem.